# My White Persian Is Peeing Everywhere

Tags: cats, behavior, health

I have this adorable Male White Persian Cat which would be almost 3 or 3 1/2 and recently I've encountered a problem. He has started pee on my things such as my comforters and carpets. He is litter trained and knows where the litter is however this has happened on two occasions and I'm trying to understand why this is happening before he ruins my things. I'd appreciate any help if possible.

Comment: A few questions: first, has anything changed, IE do you have a new cat, did you move anything, have you been keeping your windows open, etc?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I went through almost two years of trying to litter box train my two Himalayans. They peed all over the carpet, rugs, and laundrey. Feliway, Nature's Miracle, vet visits, letting them outside, every kind of cat litter, and several emotional breakdowns later, and I found them a new home. I've since been told it is a Persian trait.

Comment: I've been told that Persians may be more subject to kidney problems than many other cars, but I wouldn't dismiss this as "a Persian trait". There is a cause, and hopefully a treatable one.

Answer (score 4):

Your cat may be stressed. There may be changes in the household or his routine. You can give him catnip, provide cat scratchers. You can also buy some sprays that you spray on the cat. The sprays can be purchased at pet stores.
Your cat might be sick. Please call your veterinarian; and if you have not seen the vet lately, make an appointment.
You have to get the smell of the cat urine completely out of the item. There are cleaning agents for removing the smell. I like baking soda. You can also try Nature's Miracle, but it is expensive.
There may be a cat outside your house or your apartment. If your cat can see the other cat, or smell the other cat then he is going to spray urine all around your living space. Cats are territorial. If you have had your cat neutered, he should not be so aggressive with his spraying.

Answer (score 0):

As @traciguynup suggested: Breaking litter box protocol can be a sign that the cat is ill. I'd recommend a visit to the vet to rule that out. Kidney problems are unlikely at this age, but it could be a urinary tract infection or something of that sort.